# Cant generate hash for files from two different folder using checksum-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to generate the hash using checksum-maven-plugin from the POM file. I need to generate the hash for each file from two different folders and generate two .sha files. I tried with the below plugin in POM but it only generates the hash for the second one i.e. for *.sql.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>files</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <algorithms>
                        <algorithm>SHA-1</algorithm>
                    </algorithms>
                    <fileSets>
                        <fileSet>
                            <directory>${basedir}/locale</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.tsv</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileSet>
                    </fileSets>
                    <individualFiles>false</individualFiles>
                    <attachChecksums>true</attachChecksums>
                    <csvSummary>false</csvSummary>
                    <shasumSummary>true</shasumSummary>
                    <shasumSummaryFile>${artifactId}-${version}_locale.sha</shasumSummaryFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.nicoulaj.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>files</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <algorithms>
                        <algorithm>SHA-1</algorithm>
                    </algorithms>
                    <fileSets>
                        <fileSet>
                            <directory>${basedir}/sql</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.sql</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileSet>
                    </fileSets>
                    <individualFiles>false</individualFiles>
                    <attachChecksums>true</attachChecksums>
                    <csvSummary>false</csvSummary>
                    <shasumSummary>true</shasumSummary>
                    <shasumSummaryFile>${artifactId}-${version}_sql.sha</shasumSummaryFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You should use two executions instead of full fledged configurations including the plugin. The configuration can be separated between global configuration which is equals for all executions as you did and configuration which are only for a single execution...Furthermore it would be interesting why you need to create checksums?

Comment: Adding separate executions serves my purpose. You can add that as in answer and I'm happy to accept it. Between, I am trying to create a hash for the files so during subsequent deployment I can only push the updates files. I'm going to compare the hash of the files in that case. Appreciate your suggestion.